# Getting 'name_taken' error when creating new Slack channel via API, despite no channel with that name

Tags: slack, slack-api

I'm receiving a `name_taken` error when creating a slack channel via the API using the `conversations.create` endpoint. My code was working fine up until a couple days ago, but now I get that error no matter what slack workspace I am in, even a brand new one that has no channels other than default ones. The Slack API [docs](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.create) say that the error means "A channel cannot be created with the given name," so it likely isn't because there is already a channel with that name, but I have no idea what else would cause this issue. I also tried testing it in Postman, and I get the same error.

However, if I make the channel name I want to create gibberish, it works. This leads me to believe that it has more to do with my slack configuration than my API request, but I am at a loss as to how. I would really appreciate any help someone could provide. Below is the code that makes the API call, as well as the response I get. Thanks in advance.

Request:

```
const channelName = 'moxified'
const createdChannel = JSON.parse(await request.post(`https://slack.com/api/conversations.create`, {
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    body: `token=${slackTokenResponse.authed_user.access_token}&name=${channelName}`, //name may change
  }));
```

Response:

```
{ok: false, error: 'name_taken'}
```

Comment: Can you confirm that you are naming the channel correctly? 

Channel names may only contain lowercase letters, numbers, hyphens, and underscores, and must be 80 characters or less 

https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.create#naming

Comment: @SuyashGaur Yes the name I am trying to use is "moxified" which had been working for the past few weeks.

Comment: There is a possibility that a 'private channel' be there with the give name.

Comment: @SuyashGaur I tested it on a brand new slack workspace, so I don't think there's any way that name would have already been used, even in a private channel. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Are you working on an enterprise grid? For reference : https://slack.com/intl/en-in/pricing

Comment: Can you try adding 'team_id' argument in your call ?

Answer (score 1):

After reaching out to a Slack developer, they explained that the interference was coming from the fact that my bot's name was also 'moxified'. To quote them, "Channel namespaces can be taken up by user groups as well as a name of a bot." I still don't get why it was working for so long without issue, but I hope this helps someone else one day :)